# Best way o allow only 2 countries IP acces server

Tags: apache-2.4, firewall, vps, nftables, network-security

i have a VPS with apache2 and 3 virtual hosts, i see a lot of ips trying to accees resources that does not exist, i also see a lot of ssh incorrect users and password tying access he server, so I need ONLY ALLOW Incoming traffic to only 1 country, and also allow ALL google ads Ips also access the site and all Google robots Ips, Google crawlers and so on, and maybe all Ips of other Good crawlers.

I read various ways to make this, htacces, iptables, nftables (wich is best that iptables because manage ipv4 and 1pv6 together), github ipset-country, and some more ways.

But i need to know what is the Best because i also read that it can consume resources of vps. I also created an free account in Maxmind and have the key but i'm very confused, I read a lot but not sure yet what is the best way to do this that I need, allow only 1 or 2 countries to access my server.

Ubuntu 18.04
Apache/2.4.29

TY

Comment: fail2ban.  Port knocking for ssh.  Blanket bans of countries of bad actors.  Those would be much easier than allowing two countries, unless those two are very small.

Comment: i only need to know what is the best option regarding performance to allow only 1 o 2 countries access my web server. If its an htaccess or directly use linux firewall to block.

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple layered questions here with interleaved possible answers.

From a technical perspective, there is not a lot of difference between iptables and nftables -- one may even be implemented using the other.  You might also want to look at firewalld which is a higher level management tool.  The ipset functionality is a good idea, as it allows filtering a large list of ips without a huge performance hit.  Note that tools like fail2ban use iptables, nftables, and ipsets.

From a functional perspective, whitelisting entire countries may be difficult, and if you try, it is likely you will miss some subnets and accidentally block access to your server.  Of course, blacklisting a country is not easier.  For http / https, instead I recommend opportunistically blacklisting based on performance needs.  However, which approach you take depends on how sure you are of who should and shouldn't be accessing your server.

Rather than completely manually maintaining a whitelist or a blacklist, the easiest way to manage this would be to use something like fail2ban and enabling the built in filters so that bad actors hitting URLS that don't exist get automatically banned after a handful of hits.  Fail2ban will reduce immediate traffic, and then you can review logs and determine if some addresses (or subnets) need to be permanently blocked with either a firewalld rule or a direct iptables rule, etc.

For ssh, I recommend whitelisting only addresses that absolutely need ssh, and blacklist everything else.  I've seen thousands to tens of thousands of useless ssh hits per hour when this is not done.  If you aren't sure of your incoming ssh addresses, port knocking might help, but setting that up can be complicated.

If you block with iptables/nftables (managed by firewalld and/or fail2ban), your server becomes inaccessible to the target and appears to disappear and the attacker usually gives up and moves on.

Something like htaccess will block access but not save you much performance, as the webserver still has to respond and your server still appears as a target to the attacker.  Things like fail2ban also have the advantage of a dynamic response, where htaccess is usually static.

Comment: TY for your answer,, i know that there is not much diference between Iptables  and Nftables and there is a traslator tool. I use Ubuntu, do you say that i must install Firewalld? because it is a alternative to Iptables i think, but i shoudl use iptables on ubuntu...

Comment: firewalld is just one of several possible user interfaces to the underlying mechanism.

Comment: firewalld configuration and rules it generate is just a shame. Use ipset only for large lists.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short. If, according to your comment to the question, you are only asking what is better tool to block/permit a large sets of IP addresses, choosing between the OS firewall and Apache mod_access, then firewall is certainly the more appropriate tool. It doesn't matter which one you'll use, `iptables`/`ipset` or `nftables`, there is no functional difference, at least for your case.

---

Neither tool talks in terms of "country". There is no such term in the Internet Protocol as "country". I am not certain it is possible to obtain a current list of all IP prefixes "assigned" to some country. It is even not always obvious how to define the relation "country associated with the IP". If, say, somebody from Germany runs VM in the AWS us-west-1, will you associate the IP he is using with Germany or US? Various VPN services add some complication into the play too. So, whichever tool you choose, you will need to invent your own way to populate and maintain the permission list, deciding *for yourself* which IP addresses you should permit. You can have some help from GeoIP services, but you should not rely solely on them.

Please notice that [Apache HTTPd manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when) always stated **you should avoid using `.htaccess`** and put all the configuration into server config file. The .htaccess was intended to be only a measure for mass web hostings, where customers aren't given any way to edit the server config file. If you are admin of the server and can edit master `httpd.conf` or files explicitly included from it, never use `.haccess` and disable it (`AllowOverride None`).

This is *especially important* for your case, because .htaccess is searched for and parsed *on each request*, and if you put a large list of IP prefixes inside, it will slow your server down noticeably, both for "allowed" and "denied" requests. This is why I am ever considering "firewall vs mod_access directives [which to be put into the server config and *not* into .htaccess]". But if `mod_access` is (correctly) used like this, it would be inconvenient to maintain the list, because any change will require at least server reload. While, both `iptables`/`ipset` and `nftables` allow the use of IP sets, which are easy to update dynamically on the fly and which won't slow down each request (that much).

---

And a note about `fail2ban`. It uses `iptables`/`ipset` or `nftables` as a backend, it's just a tool to build their rules dynamically. If you have a concrete list of such rules up front, fail2ban is not needed. Also it behaves quite unexpectedly when the list of rules is large. For instance, I had a case when DDoS attack was mounted against a server which was running fail2ban, and fail2ban made the problem *much worse* that it would be without it. It is because it built the list up to around 26000 entries, but fail2ban seems to be never tested with lists such large. When we attempted to restart it, it was removing its rules one by one for an hour, then it actually restarted, and then it began adding rules back one by one for another hour. On overloaded server.

Comment: Hi, TY for the answer, yes, i know that Apache state avoid using htaccess, and that htaccess can be used to block or allow only 1 countrie but have a performance bad impact, for this reason maybe the best approach is Iptables, i'm reading this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516504/iptables-to-allow-traffic-from-one-country-only and maybe this is the best option for ONLY allow 1 countrie connect to the VPS

Comment: If you can block all but one country with a single htaccess file, it's probably a very very small country, and even then I'm not sure it can be done.  I think the world is a bigger place than you think, and trying to restrict access by country is a hopeless task that will only ever have limited success.

Comment: Read the 2nd paragraph again. Currently IPv4 full view is around 800000 routes I think, of course many of them are US, but even if that's half, the half of that split to countries is still a lot per country. No, even a single country can't be exempted using htaccess. No way.